# problema con decimales y miles

Tags: php, str-replace

tengo esta edicion para un update, donde el valor es un numero decimal con 15,2 (quince digitos enteros y 2 decimales) y reemplazo coma (,) por punto (.) para agregarlo a una base de datos.

```
    include ("connection_upload_csv.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false)
        {       {
            $entrega_importe = (str_replace(',', '.', $filesop[14]));


 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . " (entrega_importe)
VALUES ('$entrega_importe')");
                        }
```

pero tengo un problema si el numero viene del origen asi:

1.044,00

necesito que reemplace la coma del decimal por punto, y si el numero contiene un punto de los miles lo borre, o reemplace por ('') pero solo para los miles.

el resultado despues del update debe ser:

1044.00

como puedo hacer el str_replace para que realice esos dos cambios en la misma variable. `$entrega_importe =`

Comment: Vaya por delante que no se nada de PHP, pero he tenido errores similares en otros lenguajes. Esto viene arrastrado de la configuración regional del usuario, ¿Tal vez pueda ayudarte revisar esto? http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php

Comment: no ya que esto viene de un volcado de una tabla en csv, y este csv viene asi el dato, es decir antes de volcarlo debo transformarlo a lo que he comentado arriba.

Comment: ¿asumo que llega como string?

Comment: he editado la pregunta he colocado de donde viene el valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usar expresiones regulares, aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```
//Aquí remuevo los separadores de miles . que te llegan
$entrega_importe = preg_replace('/\.(\d{1,3})/', '$1', $filesop[14]);
//Aquí remuevo el separador de los decimales ,
$entrega_importe = preg_replace('/,(\d{2})$/','.$1', $entrega_importe);
```

Si $filesop tuviera el valor: 12.003.123.12,25
Lo formatearía a 1200312312.25 que según entendí era lo que buscabas.

Comment: No es un poco demasiado 2 expresiones regulares para algo que se soluciona con `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 1):

Si el dato llega como string, la conversión del punto y la coma la puedes hacer pasando arreglos como parámetros en str_replace():

```
$valor = "1.044,00";
$old = ['.', ','];
$new = ['', '.'];
$valor = str_replace($old, $new, $valor);
```

De ahí en adelante ya depende si necesitas convertirlo a float o darle formato como número y lo dejas como string:

```
$valor = floatval($valor);
```